# Why does the Clojure zipper implementation use different types and data structures from Huet's zipper?

Tags: algorithm, clojure, zipper

I'm comparing [Huet's original paper](https://www.st.cs.uni-saarland.de/edu/seminare/2005/advanced-fp/docs/huet-zipper.pdf) with [Clojure's implementation](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/zip.clj) and trying to figure out why the changes were made.  I'm a Clojure novice, so if I'm wrong on my interpretation of the Clojure code, please correct me.

In Huet's paper, the type of a path is (in Ocaml) `Top | Node of tree list * path * tree list;;`.  In Clojure, there are two additional fields, `pnodes` and `changed?`.  What's the purpose of these fields?  Am I right in believing that `l` and `r` correspond to the first and third entries in Huet's type, and that `ppath` is the second?

Huet's zipper uses linked lists throughout (note I'm talking about the Loc type itself, not the data structure the zipper is operating), while in some places, for instance `l`, the Clojure implementation uses vectors.  Why the change, and what's the implication for the Clojure implementation's time complexity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your understanding of `l`, `r` and `ppath` is correct.

`pnodes` and `changed?` work together as an optimization: when you go `up` if `changed?` is false then you pop the node from pnodes rather than rebuilding it from the current node and the left and right siblings lists.

As for the use of a vector for `l` and a list for `r`. Again it's about the cost of rebuilding a node. In Huet's paper there's `(rev left) @ (t::right)` which is O(nleft) where nleft is the size of left. In Clojure we have `(concat l (cons node r))` which is O(1) [1] because `l` being a vector does not need to be reversed (vectors in Clojure can be efficiently traversed in any direction but are appendable only at the right).

[1] ok it's O(1) only at creation time: nleft conses will be lazily allocated as the resulting sequence is consumed by further computation.